# Django login required middleware not working

Tags: python, django, middleware

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to implement the django-login-required-middleware in my project to be able to direct all the users who are not logged in to the index page with login view.

I Installed the `pip install django-login-required-middleware`, added `login_required` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` settings and added `login_required.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware` in my MIDDLEWARE. Then in my settings I ignore the views that I want to display to users even when They're not logged in.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES = [
    'index',
    'register'
]
```

However, when I run the server, I get the error

> Not Found: /accounts/login/
>   [22/Jan/2020 12:27:56] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4417

and in my browser:

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/

It seems like it automatically directs me to the accounts, even though my app is called movies_app and not accounts. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thank you very much!

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import editprofile

from . import views

app_name = 'movies_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('browse/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('movies/', views.allMovies, name='allMovies'),
    path('movies/<int:pk>/', views.movie, name='movie'),
    path('movies/<int:pk>/rate', views.addRating, name='rate'),
    path('my-list/', views.myMovies, name='my-list'),
    path('my-list/<int:pk>/delete', views.deleteFavoriteMovie, name='favorite-movie-delete'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='register'),
    path('editprofile/', views.editprofile, name='editprofile'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('movie-video', views.movieVideo, name='movie-video')
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: @Alasdair I have just added it. Thanks for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your middleware is working and redirecting you to the default login page, `/accounts/login/`.

To customise the default login page, add [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#login-url) to your settings, e.g.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

Finally, you have `app_name = 'movies_app', so you should include this when referring to URL patterns from this app. For example, your`LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES` should be:

```
LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES = [
     'movies_app:index',
     'movies_app:register'
]
```